# Passing action in <rich:modalPanel>

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

There is some way to pass action in `<rich:modalPanel>`. I want to write simple popup with "Yes" and "No" button, and I want to reuse this popup in different pages, that's why I need that different action was invoked when "Yes" button pressed. There is a way to pass some value in `<rich:modalPanel>` with `<a4j:actionparam>`:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="See details…" id="det"
    reRender="popup_dataIdField, …">

    <rich:componentControl for="popup"
        operation="show" event="onclick" />

    <a4j:actionparam name="message" assignTo="#{popupBean.message}"
        value="#{myBean.message}" />                                        
</a4j:commandButton>
```

But is some way to pass action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer by myself :). Maybe it will be helpful for somebody.

I've done this using Facelets. When I'm include popup to my page I pass parametr to it:

```
            <ui:include src="./WEB-INF/popup/popup.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="yesAction" value="${thisPageBean}" />
            </ui:include>
```

Where `thisPageBean` - is bean from what popup invoked.

Then in my popup I wrote:

```
 <a4j:commandButton id="yesButton" value="#{msgs.yesButton}"
                     action="#{yesAction.someAtion}"
 </a4j:commandButton>
```

And with this I invoke `thisPageBean.someAtion`. All magic is `${thisPageBean}`, it's is necessary to us `$` but no `#`.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using Facelets then look at [Rick Hightower's article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/) and the section "Passing Actions". It's the same basic method to what you've used, but also passing in the method on the bean.

Eg:

```
<ui:include src="./WEB-INF/popup/popup.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="yesAction" value="save"/>
  <ui:param name="cancelAction" value="cancel"/>
  <ui:param name="backingBean" value="#{thisPageBean}"/>
</ui:include>
```

And then in the popup:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="yesButton" value="#{msgs.yesButton}"
     action="#{backingBean[yesAction]}"/>
```

Note that you use the #.

Comment: Aren't it passing bean? How can I pass both bean and action?

Comment: try it first eh. the square brackets allows for the action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I dont see any problems with doing this. You can use my code if you want:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="popup" width="261" height="386"  autosized="true"left="180" top="200" keepVisualState="true">
    <h:panelGrid id="panelGrid">
        <h:outputText value="#{PopupBean.output}" id="popupMessage"/>
            <a4j:commandLink action="#">
                <h:outputText value="Close" />
                <rich:componentControl for="popup" operation="hide" event="onclick"/>
            </a4j:commandLink>
    </h:panelGrid>
</rich:modalPanel>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <a4j:commandLink action="#"  reRender="panelGrid">
        <h:outputText value="Yes" />
        <rich:componentControl for="popup" operation="show" event="onclick"/>
        <a4j:actionparam name="message" assignTo="#{PopupBean.output}" value="#{TestBean.input1}"/>
    </a4j:commandLink>
    <a4j:commandLink action="#" reRender="panelGrid">
         <h:outputText value="No" />
         <rich:componentControl for="popup" operation="show" event="onclick"/>
         <a4j:actionparam name="message2" assignTo="#{PopupBean.output}" value="#{TestBean.input2}"/>
    </a4j:commandLink>
 </h:panelGrid>
```

Basicly the output in the modal panel will contain the values in the TestBean

**Edit (the misunderstanding)**:

I believe you will have to define your modal panel like this:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="popup" width="261" height="386"  autosized="true"left="180" top="200" keepVisualState="true"
    binding="#{PopupBean.popupPanel}">
</rich:modalPanel>
```

And in your managed bean you will have to addChildren to your modal panel dynamically with java like this:

```
public String action_PoppingThePanel() {
    HtmlCommandButton button = new HtmlCommandButton();
    button.setValue("Yes");
    String action = "#{TestBean.action_yes}";
    MethodExpression methodExpression =
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory().
            createMethodExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), action, null,
            new Class<?>[0]);

    button.setActionExpression(methodExpression);
    getPopupPanel().getChildren().add(button);
    button = new HtmlCommandButton();
    button.setValue("No");
    String action = "#{TestBean.action_no}";
    methodExpression =
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory().
            createMethodExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), action, null,
            new Class<?>[0]);

    button.setActionExpression(methodExpression);
    getPopupPanel().getChildren().add(button);        
    getPopupPanel().setRendered(true);
    getPopupPanel().setShowWhenRendered(true);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You pass simple string or other value to modalPanel, but I want pass action. I want in one page when I click "ok" button in popup one method was complite, in other page other method. I want pass this method to popup. It will help me to reuse this popup.

Comment: Oh Im sorry I misunderstood your question. I will look into this for you

Comment: Thank for quick response, but I find easy solution :). See atop.