# Passing actionListener method names as arguments to include view

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I'm trying to pass action parameters to the partial view in my page but for some reason it says that my parameter is `null`, even though it's the bean that is being used in the outer page.

**Page:**

```
<ui:include src="/templates/common/ajaxConfirmPopup.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="bean" value="#{paginaBean}" />
    <ui:param name="action" value="deleteAll" />
</ui:include>
```

**Calling the action in the partial:**

```
actionListener="#{bean[action]}"
```

**But I get the following exception:**

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:98) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:244) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**NOTE:** Everything works fine when method has `ActionEvent` parameter, it is not working when method is without parameters.

Comment: Turns out that using "action" isntead of "actionListener" made it work, which solves my problem. I don't know why it doesn't work for actionListener though.

Comment: can you check is this working if `deleteAll` method has `ActionEvent` parameter? I think I had this situation sometimes ago and this soled the problem. Like this doesn't work with no-arg methods when bean is passed with `ui:param`.

Comment: Yes, id does! But I have other methods as actionListeners and they work without any parameter. i.e.: The same method work with actionListener (and no parameters) if I don't use a included view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is explainable if you have declared `actionListener` methods in EL 2.2 syntax without any arguments as follows all the time:

```
actionListener="#{bean.method()}"
```

which indeed expects an argumentless method. However, the **standard** JSF way is the following

```
actionListener="#{bean.method}"
```

which really expects an `ActionEvent` argument. Your question history indeed [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670819/jsf-hcommandbutton-dont-work-with-fajax) that you were using EL 2.2 syntax all the time and thus you somehow assumed it to be "the standard" while that's not true.

When parameterizing the `actionListener` method for an include template like as in your approach with `actionListener="#{bean[action]}"`, the `actionListener` method is been interpreted as

```
actionListener="#{bean.method}"
```

which thus expects an `ActionEvent` argument.

You have basically 3 options to fix this:

1. Specify the `ActionEvent` argument in the method, no excuses.
2. Replace `actionListener` by `action`. It's no problem to keep the method `void`. If e.g. Eclipse EL validation jerks, just [tone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083469/validation-error-on-valid-facelet-when-calling-action-method-with-parameter/8084049#8084049) it in preferences.
3. Use EL 2.2 syntax like so `actionListener="#{bean[action]()}"`. This however [fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004233/jsf-2-how-to-pass-an-action-including-an-argument-to-be-invoked-to-a-facelets-s/8004349#8004349) in early Tomcat and Glassfish versions.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)