# JSF h:CommandButton don't work with f:ajax?

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I am trying to submit a form with the following code but it doesn't populate the fields in the bean:

```
//input above
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{transferenciaVagaBean.search()}" value="Search">
  <f:ajax render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Althoug, if I change the component to:

```
//input above
<a4j:commandButton actionListener="#{transferenciaVagaBean.search()}" 
                   value="Search" 
                   render="@form" />
```

It works perfect. Am I doing something wrong using h:commandButton?

I tried to change from `actionListener` to `action` since I had problems before with this, but it didn't work either way with `h:commandButton`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `f:ajax` will only execute `@this` meaning it will only submit the action button, not any of the values of inputs in the form.  Try this:

```
...
<f:ajax execute='@form' render='@form' />
...
```

See the **execute** section of the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/):

> ... If a literal is specified the ids must be space delimited. Any of the
>   keywords "@this", "@form", "@all", "@none" may be specified in the id
>   list. If not specified, the default value of "@this" is assumed. For
>   example, @this clientIdOne clientIdTwo.

Comment: OMG. That was easy. Thanks!