# Replace only part of an EL

Tags: jsf, el

I have a template in JSF, this template have a button whose action must be different for each page that will use this template.
I wonder if there is any way to set only a part of that action.
Eg
In the template, I have the following attribute on the button:

```
disabled = "#{managedBeanTemplate.EditMode}"
```

However, for each page that will use this template, it should replace ONLY the part where it says managedBeanTemplate, thus:

```
disabled = "#{managedBeanProduct.EditMode}"
disabled = "#{managedBeanSales.EditMode}"
```

Is there any way to do this?

I know there is the ui:param to replace parts of the xhtml, but i can't nest in the template using something like this:

```
disabled = "#{#{managedBeanName}.EditMode}"
```

in the template, and then

```
<ui:param name="managedBeanName" value="managedBeanProduct"/>
```

in the page that uses the template.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say that you are using a template?  What kind of a template?  Have you looked at using `<ui:include>` and using `<ui:param>`?  Why wouldn't this work for you specifically?

Comment: it's an ui:template that i'm using. I can't use the ui:param, this is explained in the end of my first messagem, and i can't use the ui:include in the whole component, because this way i must do it in every component of the template. i would like to define only the name of the managedBean in the attribute of the component in my template page.

Comment: Thanks for posting back with the answer!  You can post your findings as an answer to your own question and accept this answer to earn more reputation points on this site.  This is the best way to post back with your findings.

Comment: Please post an answer as an answer, not as an update to the question. Please also refrain from yelling (inappropriate usage of uppercased characters) in the post.

Comment: i cant put the answer as a answer because i have not enought reputation!

Comment: Guess now you have enough rep. Please post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[facelets: passing bean name with ui:param to action attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783282/facelets-passing-bean-name-with-uiparam-to-action-attribute)
i can just do something like this in the template:

```
disabled = "#{managedBeanName['EditMode']}"
```

then, i can simply set the "managedBeanName" through the ui:param

Answer (score 0):

you would be better served having method that takes a parameter.  by having the template construct the back references to the server side you are creating a maintainance footprint where it should not be.  replace the references with a method that abstracts away the logic of whether the component is disabled/rendered/etc.

ultimately the UX should not care "why", just whether it has to render a compoenent a certain way.