# JSF: How to pass ui:param to a custom facelets tag?

Tags: jsf

I've created a custom facelets tag like this:

```
<ui:composition xmlns...>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink action="#{controller.doSomething()}"/>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

And I'm trying to use it like this:

```
<myNs:myTag>
    <ui:param name="controller" value="#{theActualController}"/>
</myNs:myTag>
```

But a click on the commandLink leads to the following exception:

```
Target Unreachable, identifier 'controller' resolved to null
```

This question [facelets: passing bean name with ui:param to action attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783282/facelets-passing-bean-name-with-uiparam-to-action-attribute) looks somewhat similar, but the solution proposed there did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a parameter with ui:param, it is possible define attributes in the taglib xml file like this:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>myTag</tag-name>
    <source>myTag.xhtml</source>
    <attribute>
        <name>controller</name>
        <required>true</requierd>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

Then pass the controller like this:

```
<myNs:myTag controller="#{theActualController}"/>
```